# specify height and width to white space trimmer image resizer

Tags: image-resizing, imageresizer

I am using image resizer creative version

i am trying to crop white space trimmer plugin.

I am able to crop the image successfully, but i want to specify the width and height so that crop should me max to it

some image crop makes image too small, so i want to avoid it

I tired this way,

```
ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(bmpStream, stream, new Instructions("trim.threshold=80&trim.percentpadding=0.5&w=250&h=250&mode=max")));
```

but it has no effect, it removing all white space arounds.

how can i specify height and width ?

Answer (score 0):

Increase the `trim.percentpadding` value to restore a certain amount of space around an object.

There is no way to set an arbitrary value for whitespace trimming that says "if the image is smaller than this, don't trim". If you have images that you don't want to be trimmed, don't add the querystring.

`width`, `height`, `scale`, and `mode` can be used to achieve pretty much any effect you need. If, for example, you want to add padding to an image to ensure it is exactly a given size, you can use `?width=100&height=100&mode=crop&scale=canvas`.

Comment: so this should be like this "trim.threshold=80&trim.percentpadding=0.5&width=250&height=250&mode=crop&scale=canvas"

Comment: I tried but its cropping some part of image too other than white space

Comment: WhitespaceTrimmer crops off all whitespace *prior* to any other cropping you do.

Comment: is there any option to say don't crop other than white color space

Comment: No &mdash; at least not in the current release. It is open-source, though, so you could connect WhitespaceTrimmer and CropAround to get the result you're looking for.